# Does embedding youtube videos help SEO?

Tags: seo

I hear lots of people talk about videos as being good for SEO, like it is more and different content.

But to imbed a video, youtube makes it an iFrame, which means it can't be crawled by google, right?

So then if it can't get crawled, its irrelevant for SEO, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youtube videos do not directly SEO. Besides the fact that they are iframes they don't have any actual crawlable content to be indexed. They can possibly help you if other sites link to your page hosting the video, but the actual video itself does not affect the page's relevance for any particular keywords. If anything, if no other content is on the page, it may even be considered low quality or duplicate content. (Although it would be interesting if Google used the title of the video it its ranking algorithm since it does always have access to that content).