# Best way to include Youtube videos in a website for SEO purposes

Tags: seo, youtube

I am aware of [Does embedding youtube videos help SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/does-embedding-youtube-videos-help-seo) - from 2011, and wonder if this answer is (still) valid.  I suspect the answer is no longer as accurate as it may have been as I know Google is now mining the content of videos for a start.

An SEO report I have is complaining about embedded iFrames and large page sizes - and the only explanation for this would appear to be that the site has Google Videos in iFrames (the rest of the page, including images is tiny)

My gut feel is that having these iFrames with Youtube links are likely beneficial for SEO as this appears to be the recommended way to do it.   I am aware there are other ways of doing this, like an image with a link or using an embed or object element.

Is there a clear best way to include Youtube videos in Web pages from an SEO POV ?

Comment: Wow.  Still no answer?  I was hoping to see people's OP as well.  I personally have been using https://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/  lazy load technique to load my videos.  However, I'm not sure search engines always recognize my videos as anything other than an image.